# Simple python code takes command line argument for file location and tokenizes text

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, file

The usage of this Python program is:

```
python ~/test.py test.txt
```

Here is the source:

```
import sys
#Open file passed by terminal
if len(sys.argv)==2:

    try:
        open(sys.argv[1])
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile:
            #Iterate through lines
            for line in inputfile:
                #tokenize
                words=line.split()
                #print tokens separated by commas
                print(",".join(words))
        inputfile.close
        sys.exit(0)

    except:
        sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(-1)
```

This is the "test.txt"

```
\ / input("       ")
input(print("some text"))

             one        two                 three
other                    things                  here
             more stuff on this    line

garbage
\n
%20
```

and it should output (which it does):

```
\,/,input(",")
input(print("some,text"))

one,two,three
other,things,here
more,stuff,on,this,line

garbage
\n
%20
```

But I'm wondering if there is some unexpected way to break it. Is there a way to nest carriage returns or something somewhere? Oh, and I realize that I can accomplish the same thing with:

```
print(",".join(line.split()))
```

But for this specific instance, I would like to separate the two steps.

Comment: 1. The question is too broad 2. It sounds you are trying to break down an application, and this later one is not funny to ask for it here.

Comment: 1. Is there a way to phrase it to be more specific? I am just trying to see if the way that I am validating input is sufficient. 2. Not trying to break an app. I'm trying to break code that I have personally written, because thats one method that I use to improve my coding.

Comment: I think this could become a good question - it seems that what you want is a review of your test cases, in which case you should post the test program and ask for a review of it.

Comment: @TobySpeight I reworded the question and added a couple lines of code for thoroughness. Is this what you were talking about? This is the extent of what I have code and text-wise. I am trying to keep it simple to learn more about this particular part of I/O handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few redundant and unnecessary calls in there.

1. Calling `open(sys.argv[1])` right before `with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile:` does not do anything.
2. The `with` statement already takes care of closing the file. So you don't need the `inputfile.close`
3. If `with` did not close your file, it would not be closed, because you actually need to call that method (so `inputfile.close()`)
4. You should never have a bare `except`. This catches more than you want, including, for example, the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Always use as specific an exception as possible. Here you probably want to except the file missing, so use either `IOError` (Python 2.x) or `FileNotFoundError` (Python 3.x)

You should also have a look at Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends surrounding operators with spaces, so `if len(sys.argv) == 2:`.

If you want this script to do something more, you should start to split the responsibilities into functions. Here you could have something like this:

```
import sys

def parse_lines(file_name):
    """Parse the lines of file_names into comma-separated lists"""
    with open(file_name) as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            yield ",".join(line.split())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Open file passed by terminal
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        try:
            for line in parse_lines(sys.argv[1]):
                print(line)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"File {sys.argv[1]} not found")
            sys.exit(-1)
```

Here I put the parsing into a function, which is actually a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). It yields the parsed lines one by one. I also added a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) describing the function.

I also made your error handling code more specific. Your code actually makes debugging your program harder, because the program returning -1 (regardless of the error encountered) is  a lot less clear than Python creating a stacktrace. If you do catch errors, you should handle them (and give the user feedback if necessary). This uses Python 3.6's new [f-strings](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/).